# Jetpack Compose Retrofit multiple GET query one of which is variable and display photos with Coil

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm following Google Android Developer codelab and I'm at a project called "Bookshelf". The main idea is to use Google APIs for books in order to:

1. retrieve list of books and their associated ids ( https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=jazz+history )

```json
{
  "kind": "books#volumes",
  "totalItems": 2542,
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "books#volume",
      "id": "C1MI_4nZyD4C",
      "etag": "U0ZwtTrieGA",
      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/C1MI_4nZyD4C",
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "The History of Jazz",
        "authors": [
          "Ted Gioia"
        ],
        "publisher": "Oxford University Press, USA",
        "publishedDate": "1997-11-20",
        "description": "Jazz is the most colorful and varied art form in the world and it was born in one of the most colorful and varied cities, New Orleans. From the seed first planted by slave dances held in Congo Square and nurtured by early ensembles led by Buddy Belden and Joe \"King\" Oliver, jazz began its long winding odyssey across America and around the world, giving flower to a thousand different forms--swing, bebop, cool jazz, jazz-rock fusion--and a thousand great musicians. Now, in The History of Jazz, Ted Gioia tells the story of this music as it has never been told before, in a book that brilliantly portrays the legendary jazz players, the breakthrough styles, and the world in which it evolved. Here are the giants of jazz and the great moments of jazz history--Jelly Roll Morton (\"the world's greatest hot tune writer\"), Louis Armstrong (whose O-keh recordings of the mid-1920s still stand as the most significant body of work that jazz has produced), Duke Ellington at the Cotton Club, cool jazz greats such as Gerry Mulligan, Stan Getz, and Lester Young, Charlie Parker's surgical precision of attack, Miles Davis's 1955 performance at the Newport Jazz Festival, Ornette Coleman's experiments with atonality, Pat Metheny's visionary extension of jazz-rock fusion, the contemporary sounds of Wynton Marsalis, and the post-modernists of the Knitting Factory. Gioia provides the reader with lively portraits of these and many other great musicians, intertwined with vibrant commentary on the music they created. Gioia also evokes the many worlds of jazz, taking the reader to the swamp lands of the Mississippi Delta, the bawdy houses of New Orleans, the rent parties of Harlem, the speakeasies of Chicago during the Jazz Age, the after hours spots of corrupt Kansas city, the Cotton Club, the Savoy, and the other locales where the history of jazz was made. And as he traces the spread of this protean form, Gioia provides much insight into the social context in which the music was born. He shows for instance how the development of technology helped promote the growth of jazz--how ragtime blossomed hand-in-hand with the spread of parlor and player pianos, and how jazz rode the growing popularity of the record industry in the 1920s. We also discover how bebop grew out of the racial unrest of the 1940s and '50s, when black players, no longer content with being \"entertainers,\" wanted to be recognized as practitioners of a serious musical form. Jazz is a chameleon art, delighting us with the ease and rapidity with which it changes colors. Now, in Ted Gioia's The History of Jazz, we have at last a book that captures all these colors on one glorious palate. Knowledgeable, vibrant, and comprehensive, it is among the small group of books that can truly be called classics of jazz literature.",
        "industryIdentifiers": [
          {
            "type": "ISBN_13",
            "identifier": "9780199840298"
          },
          {
            "type": "ISBN_10",
            "identifier": "0199840296"
          }
        ],
        "readingModes": {
          "text": true,
          "image": true
        },
        "pageCount": 481,
        "printType": "BOOK",
        "categories": [
          "Social Science"
        ],
        "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
        "allowAnonLogging": false,
        "contentVersion": "1.2.2.0.preview.3",
        "panelizationSummary": {
          "containsEpubBubbles": false,
          "containsImageBubbles": false
        },
        "imageLinks": {
          "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
          "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "language": "en",
        "previewLink": "http://books.google.ie/books?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=jazz+history&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",
        "infoLink": "http://books.google.ie/books?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&dq=jazz+history&hl=&source=gbs_api",
        "canonicalVolumeLink": "https://books.google.com/books/about/The_History_of_Jazz.html?hl=&id=C1MI_4nZyD4C"
      },
      "saleInfo": {
        "country": "IE",
        "saleability": "NOT_FOR_SALE",
        "isEbook": false
      },
      "accessInfo": {
        "country": "IE",
        "viewability": "PARTIAL",
        "embeddable": true,
        "publicDomain": false,
        "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
        "epub": {
          "isAvailable": true,
          "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.ie/books/download/The_History_of_Jazz-sample-epub.acsm?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "pdf": {
          "isAvailable": true,
          "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.ie/books/download/The_History_of_Jazz-sample-pdf.acsm?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&format=pdf&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "webReaderLink": "http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&hl=&source=gbs_api",
        "accessViewStatus": "SAMPLE",
        "quoteSharingAllowed": false
      },
      "searchInfo": {
        "textSnippet": "Now, in The History of Jazz, Ted Gioia tells the story of this music as it has never been told before, in a book that brilliantly portrays the legendary jazz players, the breakthrough styles, and the world in which it evolved."
      }
    },
[...]
}
```

2. perform a second GET query with the book id to retrieve it's details ( example: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/C1MI_4nZyD4C )

```json
{
  "kind": "books#volume",
  "id": "C1MI_4nZyD4C",
  "etag": "ljZDWl6LzoA",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/C1MI_4nZyD4C",
  "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "The History of Jazz",
    "authors": [
      "Ted Gioia"
    ],
    "publisher": "Oxford University Press, USA",
    "publishedDate": "1997-11-20",
    "description": "Jazz is the most colorful and varied art form in the world and it was born in one of the most colorful and varied cities, New Orleans. From the seed first planted by slave dances held in Congo Square and nurtured by early ensembles led by Buddy Belden and Joe \"King\" Oliver, jazz began its long winding odyssey across America and around the world, giving flower to a thousand different forms--swing, bebop, cool jazz, jazz-rock fusion--and a thousand great musicians. Now, in The History of Jazz, Ted Gioia tells the story of this music as it has never been told before, in a book that brilliantly portrays the legendary jazz players, the breakthrough styles, and the world in which it evolved. Here are the giants of jazz and the great moments of jazz history--Jelly Roll Morton (\"the world's greatest hot tune writer\"), Louis Armstrong (whose O-keh recordings of the mid-1920s still stand as the most significant body of work that jazz has produced), Duke Ellington at the Cotton Club, cool jazz greats such as Gerry Mulligan, Stan Getz, and Lester Young, Charlie Parker's surgical precision of attack, Miles Davis's 1955 performance at the Newport Jazz Festival, Ornette Coleman's experiments with atonality, Pat Metheny's visionary extension of jazz-rock fusion, the contemporary sounds of Wynton Marsalis, and the post-modernists of the Knitting Factory. Gioia provides the reader with lively portraits of these and many other great musicians, intertwined with vibrant commentary on the music they created. Gioia also evokes the many worlds of jazz, taking the reader to the swamp lands of the Mississippi Delta, the bawdy houses of New Orleans, the rent parties of Harlem, the speakeasies of Chicago during the Jazz Age, the after hours spots of corrupt Kansas city, the Cotton Club, the Savoy, and the other locales where the history of jazz was made. And as he traces the spread of this protean form, Gioia provides much insight into the social context in which the music was born. He shows for instance how the development of technology helped promote the growth of jazz--how ragtime blossomed hand-in-hand with the spread of parlor and player pianos, and how jazz rode the growing popularity of the record industry in the 1920s. We also discover how bebop grew out of the racial unrest of the 1940s and '50s, when black players, no longer content with being \"entertainers,\" wanted to be recognized as practitioners of a serious musical form. Jazz is a chameleon art, delighting us with the ease and rapidity with which it changes colors. Now, in Ted Gioia's The History of Jazz, we have at last a book that captures all these colors on one glorious palate. Knowledgeable, vibrant, and comprehensive, it is among the small group of books that can truly be called classics of jazz literature.",
    "industryIdentifiers": [
      {
        "type": "ISBN_10",
        "identifier": "0199840296"
      },
      {
        "type": "ISBN_13",
        "identifier": "9780199840298"
      }
    ],
    "readingModes": {
      "text": true,
      "image": true
    },
    "pageCount": 480,
    "printedPageCount": 481,
    "printType": "BOOK",
    "categories": [
      "Social Science / Ethnic Studies / African American Studies",
      "History / United States / 20th Century"
    ],
    "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
    "allowAnonLogging": false,
    "contentVersion": "1.2.2.0.preview.3",
    "panelizationSummary": {
      "containsEpubBubbles": false,
      "containsImageBubbles": false
    },
    "imageLinks": {
      "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE730biSUWPH7wghApGEceQgvs4lpFCTDDGPT0dIp-EkMCBA1sLvNEGHhvoxr8_43Mtp-RTxRA-gZrTn1tc4rq9id-v8u7fvveuxUnrm3JfbRl-umhSHYDfo0S_PqhutDGS0mcpV1&source=gbs_api",
      "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE70rZqUfLNXAlZ3Mp6KorU6BzZ2x_p528N9jzQZIV4WuRWVVJFT0A8SQy0WJBttQ3IWtTf6AoEW237Xu8O1vlNWxhibKUq4pt-ktxHLHieX-Y0lqoUgmMccjHtQSuvplVDtmBBGp&source=gbs_api",
      "small": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=2&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE73RkCaP-LV0p65fciM3whXa6bbzVML38bukLHbCPhO6F2ecP6npI9UBmYw03reO6qT6NjAVLf9m8e788OLtrto-eGpGj2AZ9qPXlA7ja7Kffx0JbC_8v3gN7U-6Tfv_Jw5JM1FK&source=gbs_api",
      "medium": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=3&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE70RBCOlwTFLS4ePUbKtMrE5P7UcdCedUtle3QhK5Q9UqgksVIHqiaqxkwxIsNFv1xKnd0xxsrOVaGhegawAmqqoGgbfdCl3hJZ9e6K6dM6aihXY16JEvsWAaQrBv6IXgfGtU2HG&source=gbs_api"
    },
    "language": "en",
    "previewLink": "http://books.google.ie/books?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&hl=&source=gbs_api",
    "infoLink": "https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&source=gbs_api",
    "canonicalVolumeLink": "https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C"
  },
  "layerInfo": {
    "layers": [
      {
        "layerId": "geo",
        "volumeAnnotationsVersion": "6"
      }
    ]
  },
  "saleInfo": {
    "country": "IE",
    "saleability": "NOT_FOR_SALE",
    "isEbook": false
  },
  "accessInfo": {
    "country": "IE",
    "viewability": "PARTIAL",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicDomain": false,
    "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
    "epub": {
      "isAvailable": true,
      "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.ie/books/download/The_History_of_Jazz-sample-epub.acsm?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
    },
    "pdf": {
      "isAvailable": true,
      "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.ie/books/download/The_History_of_Jazz-sample-pdf.acsm?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&format=pdf&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
    },
    "webReaderLink": "http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=C1MI_4nZyD4C&hl=&source=gbs_api",
    "accessViewStatus": "SAMPLE",
    "quoteSharingAllowed": false
  }
}
```

the app should display the `thumbnail` photo from `imageLinks` object for each book fetched from the API asynchronously using Coil

#### what I'm doing

I've defined the following **Serializable** data classes:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class BookshelfBook(
    val items: List<Map<String, String>>
)
```

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class BookshelfVolume(
    val imageLinks: Map<String, String>
)
```

and I'm trying to fetch data using the following API interface

```kotlin
interface BookshelfApiService {
    @GET("?q=jazz+history")
    suspend fun getBooks(): List<BookshelfBook>

    @GET("{volume_id}")
    suspend fun getVolume(bookId: String): List<BookshelfVolume>
}
```

tying it all together in the following repository:

```kotlin
interface BookshelfRepository {
    suspend fun getBookshelfBooks(): List<BookshelfBook>
    suspend fun getBookshelfVolumes(books: List<BookshelfBook>): List<BookshelfVolume>
}

class NetworkBookshelfRepository(
    private val bookshelfApiService: BookshelfApiService
) : BookshelfRepository {
    override suspend fun getBookshelfBooks(): List<BookshelfBook> =
        bookshelfApiService.getBooks()

    override suspend fun getBookshelfVolumes(books: List<BookshelfBook>): List<BookshelfVolume> =
ERROR --->        listOf(books.forEach { bookshelfApiService.getVolume(it["id"]) })
}
```

with the following error when trying to build a list of `BookshelfVolume`s in `override suspend fun getBookShelfVolumes`:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is List<Unit> but List<BookshelfVolume> was expected
```

these are used in the ViewModel:

```kotlin
package com.example.bookshelf.ui.model

import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.Companion.APPLICATION_KEY
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.initializer
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.viewModelFactory
import com.example.bookshelf.BookshelfApplication
import com.example.bookshelf.data.BookshelfRepository
import com.example.bookshelf.network.BookshelfVolume
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.io.IOException

sealed interface BookshelfUiState {
    data class Success(val volumes: List<BookshelfVolume>): BookshelfUiState
    object Loading: BookshelfUiState
    object Error: BookshelfUiState
}

class BookshelfViewModel(
    private val bookshelfRepository: BookshelfRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    var bookshelfUiState: BookshelfUiState by mutableStateOf(BookshelfUiState.Loading)
        private set

    init {
        getBookshelfVolumes()
    }

    fun getBookshelfVolumes() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            bookshelfUiState = try {
                val books = bookshelfRepository.getBookshelfBooks()
                BookshelfUiState.Success(bookshelfRepository.getBookshelfVolumes(books))
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                BookshelfUiState.Error
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val Factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                val application = (this[APPLICATION_KEY] as BookshelfApplication)
                val bookshelfRepository = application.container.bookshelfRepository
                BookshelfViewModel(bookshelfRepository = bookshelfRepository)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so, in principle:

1. fetch list of books with their associated IDs
2. for each book given its ID, fetch it's details and build a list "thumbnail" links so that they can be passed to Coil

---

#### where I'm stuck

I am unsure how to fix the repository such that I can build a list of `BookshelfVolume`s for each book fetched (`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=jazz+history` call)

any hints on how to

1. satisfy `@GET("{volume_id}")` in the `BookshelfApiService` interface when calling `getVolume(bookId: String)` for each id of the books fetched using `@GET("?q=jazz+history")` call in same `BookshelfApiService`
2. build a list of "thumbnail" links by parsing "imageLinks" map of each book fetched details (volume)

?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with the following

#### BookshelfApiService.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.bookshelf.network

import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Path

interface BookshelfApiService {
    @GET("?q=jazz+history")
    suspend fun getBooks(): List<BookshelfBook>

    @GET("{volume_id}")
    suspend fun getVolume(@Path("id") id: String): BookshelfVolume
}
```

#### BookshelfBook.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.bookshelf.network

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class BookshelfBook(
    val id: String
)
```

#### BookshelfVolume.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.bookshelf.network

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class BookshelfVolume(
    val imageLinks: Map<String, String>
)
```

#### BookshelfRepository.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.bookshelf.data

import com.example.bookshelf.network.BookshelfApiService
import com.example.bookshelf.network.BookshelfBook
import com.example.bookshelf.network.BookshelfVolume

interface BookshelfRepository {
    suspend fun getBookshelfBooks(): List<BookshelfBook>
    suspend fun getBookshelfVolume(id: String): BookshelfVolume
}

class NetworkBookshelfRepository(
    private val bookshelfApiService: BookshelfApiService
) : BookshelfRepository {
    override suspend fun getBookshelfBooks(): List<BookshelfBook> =
        bookshelfApiService.getBooks()

    override suspend fun getBookshelfVolume(id: String): BookshelfVolume =
        bookshelfApiService.getVolume(id)
}
```

#### BookshelfViewModel.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.bookshelf.ui.model

import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.Companion.APPLICATION_KEY
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.initializer
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.viewModelFactory
import com.example.bookshelf.BookshelfApplication
import com.example.bookshelf.data.BookshelfRepository
import com.example.bookshelf.network.BookshelfVolume
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.io.IOException

sealed interface BookshelfUiState {
    data class Success(val volumes: List<BookshelfVolume>): BookshelfUiState
    object Loading: BookshelfUiState
    object Error: BookshelfUiState
}

class BookshelfViewModel(
    private val bookshelfRepository: BookshelfRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    var bookshelfUiState: BookshelfUiState by mutableStateOf(BookshelfUiState.Loading)
        private set

    init {
        getBookshelfVolumes()
    }

    fun getBookshelfVolumes() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            bookshelfUiState = try {
                val books = bookshelfRepository.getBookshelfBooks().map { it.id }
                val volumes = books.map { id ->
                    bookshelfRepository.getBookshelfVolume(id)
                }
                BookshelfUiState.Success(volumes)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                BookshelfUiState.Error
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val Factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                val application = (this[APPLICATION_KEY] as BookshelfApplication)
                val bookshelfRepository = application.container.bookshelfRepository
                BookshelfViewModel(bookshelfRepository = bookshelfRepository)
            }
        }
    }
}
```